# Place a box on the top and in the center

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to place four blue boxes in the grid. First I wanted to start with one blue box in the center and in the top. Unfortunately I can't even figure one box out to place it right.
I've tried to make two boxes and one panel. I've tried with a static text and it worked, so I wanted to adapt that principle with the box, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Could you have a look into it to see what I've done wrong?

What I want to achieve is this:

[image]

Here's below is my code:

```
    import wx
class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        panel1 = self.panels()
        self.boxes(panel1)

    def panels(self):
        panel1 = wx.Panel(self)
        panel1.SetBackgroundColour([0, 178, 202])
        return panel1

    def boxes(self,panel1):
        hbluebox1 = wx.BoxSizer()
        vbluebox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        hbluebox1.Add(panel1, 6, wx.ALIGN_TOP)
        vbluebox1.Add(hbluebox1, 6, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        self.SetSizer(vbluebox1)
        return vbluebox1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    class Screen(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(600, 400))
            framebox = wx.BoxSizer()
            panel = Panel(self)
            framebox.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
            self.SetSizer(framebox)
            self.Show()
    app = wx.App()
    Screen(None, -1, "Kleuruitdager 2")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: why do you need it ? Maybe you should use Canvas and draw rectangles?

Comment: I have to use boxes and panels, but I want to make it like the image for practice.

Comment: what `box` do you mean ? `BoxSizer` is only `layout manager` to organize other widgets - and it doesn't have size if it is empty. maybe you should use some `grid layout manager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with simple coloured panels and a `wx.GridBagSizer`

I'll leave you to finish off the tweaking and a central panel (perhaps achieved in a similar manner).
The other option, is of course, to start drawing, as suggested in the comments.

```
import wx

class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(3, 3)
        top_lpanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=(100, 100))
        top_mpanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=(100, 100))
        top_rpanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=(100, 100))
        top_lpanel.SetBackgroundColour("white")
        top_mpanel.SetBackgroundColour("blue")
        top_rpanel.SetBackgroundColour("white")
        
        mid_lpanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=(100, 100))
        mid_mpanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=(100, 100))
        mid_rpanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=(100, 100))
        mid_lpanel.SetBackgroundColour("blue")
        mid_mpanel.SetBackgroundColour("white")
        mid_rpanel.SetBackgroundColour("blue")
        
        bot_lpanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=(100, 100))
        bot_mpanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=(100, 100))
        bot_rpanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=(100, 100))
        bot_lpanel.SetBackgroundColour("white")
        bot_mpanel.SetBackgroundColour("blue")
        bot_rpanel.SetBackgroundColour("white")
        
        sizer.Add(top_lpanel, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.EXPAND, border = 10)
        sizer.Add(top_mpanel, pos=(0, 1), flag=wx.EXPAND, border = 10)
        sizer.Add(top_rpanel, pos=(0, 2), flag=wx.EXPAND, border = 10)
        sizer.Add(mid_lpanel, pos=(1, 0), flag=wx.EXPAND, border = 10)
        sizer.Add(mid_mpanel, pos=(1, 1), flag=wx.EXPAND, border = 10)
        sizer.Add(mid_rpanel, pos=(1, 2), flag=wx.EXPAND, border = 10)
        sizer.Add(bot_lpanel, pos=(2, 0), flag=wx.EXPAND, border = 10)
        sizer.Add(bot_mpanel, pos=(2, 1), flag=wx.EXPAND, border = 10)
        sizer.Add(bot_rpanel, pos=(2, 2), flag=wx.EXPAND, border = 10)                
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    class Scherm(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            framebox = wx.BoxSizer()
            panel = Panel(self)
            framebox.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
            self.SetSizerAndFit(framebox)
            self.Show()
    
    app = wx.App()
    Scherm(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help, today I finally figured it out how to do it. Now I get the principle how to do it.
[Endresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxIQQ.png)

```
import wx


class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        #blue and non-colored boxes
        left_panel1 = self.box1()
        mid_panel1, white_box = self.box2()
        right_panel1 = self.box3()
        #yellow_boxes
        mid_yellow_panel1 = self.yellow_top1()
        mid_yellow_panel2 = self.yellow_top2()
        mid_yellow_panel3 = self.yellow_top3()
        #box for the yellow boxes
        self.yellow_boxes(white_box, mid_yellow_panel1, mid_yellow_panel2, mid_yellow_panel3)
        #The mainbox
        main_box = self.boxes(left_panel1, mid_panel1, right_panel1)
        self.SetSizer(main_box)

    def box1(self):
        left_panel1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # 1e witte box
        white_top1 = wx.Panel(self)
        # 1e witte box in de grote box
        left_panel1.Add(white_top1, 7, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        # 1e blauwe box
        blue_top1 = wx.Panel(self)
        blue_top1.SetBackgroundColour([0, 178, 202])
        # Voegt 1e blauwe box toe in de grote box
        left_panel1.Add(blue_top1, 6, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        # 2e witte box
        white_bottom1 = wx.Panel(self)
        # 2e witte box in de grote box
        left_panel1.Add(white_bottom1, 7, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        return left_panel1

    def box2(self):
        mid_panel1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # 1e blauwe box
        blue_top1 = wx.Panel(self)
        blue_top1.SetBackgroundColour([0, 178, 202])
        # Voegt 1e blauwe box toe in de grote box
        mid_panel1.Add(blue_top1, 6, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        # 1e witte box
        white_box = wx.BoxSizer()
        # 1e witte box in de grote box
        mid_panel1.Add(white_box, 7, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        # 2e blauwe box
        blue_top1 = wx.Panel(self)
        blue_top1.SetBackgroundColour([0, 178, 202])
        # Voegt 1e blauwe box toe in de grote box
        mid_panel1.Add(blue_top1, 6, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        return mid_panel1, white_box

    def box3(self):
        right_panel1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # 1e witte box
        white_top1 = wx.Panel(self)
        # 1e witte box in de grote box
        right_panel1.Add(white_top1, 7, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        # 1e blauwe box
        blue_top1 = wx.Panel(self)
        blue_top1.SetBackgroundColour([0, 178, 202])
        # Voegt 1e blauwe box toe in de grote box
        right_panel1.Add(blue_top1, 6, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        # 2e witte box
        white_bottom1 = wx.Panel(self)
        # 2e witte box in de grote box
        right_panel1.Add(white_bottom1, 7, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        return right_panel1

    #Yellow panels
    def yellow_top1(self):
        mid_yellow_panel1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # 1e witte box
        white_top1 = wx.Panel(self)
        # 1e witte box in de grote box
        mid_yellow_panel1.Add(white_top1, 3, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        # 1e gele box
        yellow_top = wx.Panel(self)
        yellow_top.SetBackgroundColour(wx.YELLOW)
        # Voegt 1e gele box toe in de grote box
        mid_yellow_panel1.Add(yellow_top, 2, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        # 2e witte box
        white_bottom1 = wx.Panel(self)
        # 2e witte box in de grote box
        mid_yellow_panel1.Add(white_bottom1, 3, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        return mid_yellow_panel1

    def yellow_top2(self):
        mid_yellow_panel2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # 1e gele box
        yellow_top = wx.Panel(self)
        yellow_top.SetBackgroundColour(wx.YELLOW)
        # Voegt 1e gele box toe in de grote box
        mid_yellow_panel2.Add(yellow_top, 2, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        # 1e witte box
        white_top1 = wx.Panel(self)
        # 1e witte box in de grote box
        mid_yellow_panel2.Add(white_top1, 4, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        # 2e gele box
        yellow_top = wx.Panel(self)
        yellow_top.SetBackgroundColour(wx.YELLOW)
        # Voegt 1e gele box toe in de grote box
        mid_yellow_panel2.Add(yellow_top, 2, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        return mid_yellow_panel2

    def yellow_top3(self):
        mid_yellow_panel3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # 1e witte box
        white_top1 = wx.Panel(self)
        # 1e witte box in de grote box
        mid_yellow_panel3.Add(white_top1, 3, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        # 1e gele box
        yellow_top = wx.Panel(self)
        yellow_top.SetBackgroundColour(wx.YELLOW)
        # Voegt 1e gele box toe in de grote box
        mid_yellow_panel3.Add(yellow_top, 2, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        # 2e witte box
        white_bottom1 = wx.Panel(self)
        # 2e witte box in de grote box
        mid_yellow_panel3.Add(white_bottom1, 3, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        return mid_yellow_panel3

    def yellow_boxes(self, white_box, mid_yellow_panel1, mid_yellow_panel2, mid_yellow_panel3):
        white_box.Add(mid_yellow_panel1, 8, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        white_box.Add(mid_yellow_panel2, 8, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        white_box.Add(mid_yellow_panel3, 8, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        return white_box

    def boxes(self, left_panel1, mid_panel1, right_panel1):
        main_box = wx.BoxSizer()
        main_box.Add(left_panel1, 20, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        main_box.Add(mid_panel1, 20, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        main_box.Add(right_panel1, 20, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        return main_box



if __name__ == '__main__':
    class Scherm(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, size1):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, size = size1)
            framebox = wx.BoxSizer()
            panel = Panel(self)
            framebox.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
            self.SetSizer(framebox)
            self.Show()


    app = wx.App()
    Scherm(None, (600, 600))
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I'm happy to see that you have grasped the flexibility of sizers. You could have course done this with absolute sizes and absolute positioning, each panel has the option of `size=(x, y)` and `pos=(x, y)` but then it becomes difficult to maintain. Change one item and the whole thing is wrong.